# MySQL stuck on this query

Tags: mysql

Is there is something wrong with this query?
It was tested and working (quite fast) and one day just stopped - never ends (query is wrong or something with MySQL?).
I have to update table turnover taking values from sales_history. Because key is vat_no, I have to join table clients to read customer vat_no from that table.

```
TURNOVER tbl
vat_no
billing_month
turnover

SALES_HISTORY tbl
customer_number
sales_amount
...

CLIENTS tbl
customer_number
vat_no
```

...

```
UPDATE turnover t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT c.vat_no, sales_history.billing_month, sales_history.customer_number, sum(sales_amount) as turnover
  FROM sales_history 
  LEFT JOIN clients c
  ON sales_history.customer_number = c.customer_number 
  WHERE sales_history.billing_month = '2018-01-01'
  GROUP BY c.vat_no
) sales_history 
ON sales_history.vat_no = t.vat_no
SET t.turnover = turnover
WHERE t.billing_month = '2018-01-01'
```

Comment: Show please also your indexes for all tables

Comment: indexes on vat_no, customer_no, billing_month

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Why left join  in the subquery if you need  the result as  key for update ?

i think you sould use INNER JOIN

```
UPDATE turnover t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT c.vat_no, sum(sales_amount) as turnover
  FROM sales_history 
  INNER JOIN clients c ON sales_history.customer_number = c.customer_number 
  WHERE sales_history.billing_month = '2018-01-01'
    and c.vat_no  is not null
  GROUP BY c.vat_no
) s ON s.vat_no = t.vat_no

SET t.turnover = turnover
WHERE t.billing_month = '2018-01-01'
```

and for performance be sure you have a composite index  on

```
 table turnover columns (billing_month , vat_no)
```

and on

```
table clients on column  customer_number
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I changed to INNER join. Indexes were as you proposed. No progress. SHOW PROCESSLIST shows lasting forever 'Creating sort index'. Table turnover has about 15k rows with where billing_month = .... and sales_history about 60k when not grouped

Comment: are you sure you have not some  lock on the table for some others  insert or updated ..  ???  could be that you have some clients  without vat_number ??

Comment: No locks. Some clients can have no vat_no but such records would be just ignored, right? I was working on this server and just ... stopped (mariaDB)

Comment: the null value could create issue for the outer join  ... ..  better  avoid this .. answer  updated  for this  ( or you should change the ON condition .. )

Comment: I found the problem. I rearranged table turnover few times and forgot to add key on vat_no collumn (f$#@!). It was working till this day because of small amount of data - stopped when table got bigger size. Thanks for help